# APEX Modal dialog called by Modal dialog -- how to return selected data APEX 5.0

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, oracle-apex

I have a modal form dialog that has a search button that pops up
a list of contacts.
When I select a contact I would like to return the data from that contact to the previous modal dialog.
I see I can return page items using a dynamic action. But I am trying to 
return data from a column row that is selected, so I'm not quite sure how to go about returning the columns #COLUMN1#, #COLUMN2#. I was trying to attempt this with javascript but was having problems with finding the correct parent object,
using something like this:
Chained is set to NO

```
       function passBack(passVal1,passVal2,passVal3,passVal4,passVal5,passVal6,passVal7, passVal8,passVal9,passVal10,passVal11,passVal12,passVal13,passVal14,passVal15,passVal16,passVal17)
   {
    parent.apex.item("&POPUP_PAGE_APPITM."+"_RC_FIRST").setValue(passVal1);
    parent.apex.item("&POPUP_PAGE_APPITM."+"_RC_LAST").setValue(passVal2);
    parent.apex.item("&POPUP_PAGE_APPITM."+"_RC_NUMBER").setValue(passVal3);
    parent.apex.item("&POPUP_PAGE_APPITM."+"_RC_DIRECTION").setValue(passVal4);
    parent.apex.item("&POPUP_PAGE_APPITM."+"_RC_STREET").setValue(passVal5);
    parent.apex.item("&POPUP_PAGE_APPITM."+"_RC_STREET_TYPE").setValue(passVal6);
    parent.apex.item("&POPUP_PAGE_APPITM."+"_RC_POST_DIRECTION").setValue(passVal7);
    parent.apex.item("&POPUP_PAGE_APPITM."+"_RC_SUITE").setValue(passVal8);
     parent.apex.item("&POPUP_PAGE_APPITM."+"_RC_AREA").setValue(unescape(passVal9));
   parent.apex.item("&POPUP_PAGE_APPITM."+"_RC_CITY").setValue(passVal10);
   parent.apex.item("&POPUP_PAGE_APPITM."+"_RC_STATE").setValue(passVal11);
   parent.apex.item("&POPUP_PAGE_APPITM."+"_RC_ZIP").setValue(passVal12);
   parent.apex.item("&POPUP_PAGE_APPITM."+"_RC_AREA_ID").setValue(passVal7);
    parent.apex.item("&POPUP_PAGE_APPITM."+"_RC_PHONE_NUMBER1").setValue(passVal13);
   parent.apex.item("&POPUP_PAGE_APPITM."+"_RC_EMAIL_ADDRESS").setValue(passVal14);
//document.getElementById("&POPUP_PAGE_APPITM."+"_RC_EMAIL_ADDRESS2").value = passVal14;
   parent.apex.item("&POPUP_PAGE_APPITM."+"_RC_CONTACT_ID").setValue(passVal15);
    parent.apex.item("&POPUP_PAGE_APPITM."+"_RC_CONTACT_METHOD_ID").setValue('96');
    parent.apex.item("&POPUP_PAGE_APPITM."+"_RC_CONTACT_SOURCE_ID").setValue('120');
    //parent.apex.item("&POPUP_PAGE_APPITM."+"_RC_CONTACT_TYPE_ID").setFocus();

   apex.submit('CLOSE');
 //  apex.util.getTopApex().jQuery( this ).dialog( "destroy" ).remove(); 
   }
```

Comment: The Calling functions looks like this:javascript:passBack('#CONTACT_FIRST#','#CONTACT_LAST#','#ADDRESS_NUMBER#','#ADDRESS_DIRECTION#','#ADDRESS_STREET#','#ADDRESS_STREET_TYPE#','#ADDRESS_POST_DIRECTION#','#ADDRESS_SUITE#',escape('#ADDRESS_AREA#'),'#ADDRESS_CITY#','#ADDRESS_STATE#','#ADDRESS_ZIP#','#PHONE_NUMBER#','#EMAIL_ADDRESS#','#USER_CONTACT_ID#','#ADDRESS_AREA_ID#');

Comment: Also tried this: function passBack(passVal1,passVal2,passVal3,passVal4,passVal5,passVal6,passVal7, passVal8,passVal9,passVal10,passVal11,passVal12,passVal13,passVal14,passVal15,passVal16)
   {
   opener.document.getElementById("&POPUP_PAGE_APPITM."+"_RC_FIRST").value = passVal1;
   opener.document.getElementById("&POPUP_PAGE_APPITM."+"_RC_LAST").value = passVal2;
   opener.document.getElementById("&POPUP_PAGE_APPITM."+"_RC_NUMBER").value = passVal3;
   opener.document.getElementById("&POPUP_PAGE_APPITM."+"_RC_CONTACT_TYPE_ID").focus();
   window.close();
   }